# Current Location SKPulseAnimation does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, skobbler-maps

I am doing one function, when users pressed a button, map will indicate users' current location by on pulse animation annotation.

```
SKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, _currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
region.zoomLevel = 14;
self.mapView.visibleRegion = region;

SKAnnotation *CurrentLocationAnnotation = [SKAnnotation annotation];
CurrentLocationAnnotation.identifier = 1;
//CurrentLocationAnnotation.annotationType = SKAnnotationTypeMarker;
CurrentLocationAnnotation.location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, _currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
SKAnimationSettings *CurrentLocationanimationSettings = [SKAnimationSettings animationSettings];
CurrentLocationanimationSettings.animationType = SKPulseAnimation;
CurrentLocationanimationSettings.animationEasingType = SKAnimationEaseLinear;
CurrentLocationanimationSettings.duration = 7000;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:CurrentLocationAnnotation withAnimationSettings:CurrentLocationanimationSettings];
```

I tried it on simulator and iphone as well, both of them don't work at all.
How can i fix it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D cordinate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapview.delegate=self;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    [self.mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 54, 122, 21)];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.3];
    label.text = @"title";

    //create our view for the image
     UIImageView *coloredView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 5.5, 122, 75)];
    coloredView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 5.5, 122, 75)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [view1 addSubview:label];
    [view1 addSubview:coloredView1];

     //create our view for the background image
    UIImageView *coloredView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 136, 110)];
    coloredView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapMarker"];
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 5.5, 122, 75)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [view2 addSubview:coloredView2];
    [view2 addSubview:view1];

    //create our view for the background image

   UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 136, 200)];
    view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [view3 addSubview:view2];

    SKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[SKAnnotationView alloc] initWithView:customAnnotationView reuseIdentifier:@"reusableIdentifier"];

    SKAnnotation *annotation = [SKAnnotation annotation];
    annotation.identifier = 123456;
    annotation.location = region.center;
    annotation.annotationView = annotationView;

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation withAnimationSettings:[SKAnimationSettings animationSettings]];

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    static NSString *identifier = @"myAnnotation";
    DraggableAnnotationView * annotationView = (DraggableAnnotationView *)[self.mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[DraggableAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_map_pin.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    annotationView.delegate = self;

    return annotationView;
}
```

if this code helpful for you then give your vote ... thank you